# Best tool to cut out back of kitchen sink cabinet?

Tags: powertools, demolition

There are 100% mice under my kitchen sink. I need to rip out the cabinet part to see whether and how I can patch it up to keep them out. I'm digging in from outside beyond the foundation, too, but that is another story. What tool do I need to cut the back of the undercabinet under my sink? I don't want to remove plumbing or countertop or even sidewalls and doors, but the floor of the cabinet may have to go if they are under it. I feel like a circular saw would be too unwieldy and large, and I want something the size of a sander. Thank you. Tool illiterate.

Answer (score 6):

Oscillating Saw or also called multitool is the best for tight places where you really want to control the action. There are many brands out there. The inventer was Fein tools. They are a cool tool for many other purposes.Good luck

Comment: You'll never regret buying a Fein multi saw, it allows you to get into areas and make cuts impossible to do any other way. Cuts just like this. Jigsaw blades are too long and cannot get right up to edges like the Fein can. With a careful hand, the multisaw blade goes barely a whisper beyond the material.

Answer (score 1):

Variable speed electric jigsaw. The variable speed feature will help you control the tool (important for a novice) and there are lightweight and compact versions that perform well.